# Select MySQL column/row with comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Suppose I have the following table information

```
+-------------+---------------+
+     id      +    letters    +
+-------------+---------------+ 
+      1      + a, b, c, d, e +  
+-------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to capture the values of the column and store them in variables:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT letters FROM tbl WHERE id=1");    
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

// Declare captured db variables
$letter1 = ** what comes here? **;
$letter2 = ** what comes here? **;
}
```

Comment: Soooo you use comma seperation in a relational database?

Comment: Lolx.  But,  this question has nothing to do with databases. It is simply "how do I split a string which contains (a) separator character(s)"?

Comment: Not really and answer but this is a bad smell fot your database design. Should you have a Letters table with reference to id and five entries?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT letters FROM tbl WHERE id=1");
$letters = explode(',',mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Now you can access any letter using an array, like this `$letters[0]; //a`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT letters FROM tbl WHERE id=1");    
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    // Declare captured db variables
   /* list($letter1,$letter2,$letter3,$letter4,$letter5) = explode(',' , $data['letters']);
    */
     $letters = array();
     // letters array will have the exploded letters     
     $letters = explode(',' , $data['letters']);
}
```

Your question is unclear. Please provide more details for a better answer :)

Comment: And if he got six parameters from the database ? And store values separated by comma... By the way, do not use mysql_* functions

Comment: The question is unclear maybe... But use mysqli, change the relationship to a one to many [...] seems helpful.

Comment: and yea.. a third table should have been used here @Debflav

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having

> $letter1
>
> $letter2

I would make an' array with explode.

```
$letter = explode(',', $data['letters']);
```

That way you can acccess your letters with a simple $letter[0] or $letter[1]

Now the above code works from the assumption that you only run through the while loop ONCE.

If you run through the while loop more than once, I'd do it like this:

```
$letter[] = explode(',', $data['letters']);
```

which is accessed by $letter[0][0] - The first [] being the instance of number when it was fetched, the second [] being the letter you want to fetch.

**Another thing**

Mysql is outdated / not gonna be used / very unsecure so I would advice you to find another alternative to mysql, such as mysqli or PDO - It is better to use these while you are learning because that way you avoid getting stuck with bad routines.